# Get Model of the selected Item in RecyclerView

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin.Android. I am building a social platform type application and I am facing difficulty in retrieving the values of selected position item in a `RecyclerView`. Scenario is that when user logs in he will get his news feed from the server which I have successfully displayed using a `RecyclerView`. There is a like button (`CheckBox`) on each item. When user presses the like button, I have to send an API call and pass the `feedID` parameter with it. I am unable to get the `feedID`. My code is:

Model:

```
public class NewsfeedCard
{
    public string FeedId { get; set; }
    public string UserPhoto { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int PersonThanked { get; set; }
    public int PersonThought { get; set; }
    public bool AlreadyLiked { get; set; }
    public bool AlreadyReported { get; set; }
}
```

ViewHolder:

```
public class NewsfeedViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public ImageView Image { get; private set; }
    public TextView UserDesription { get; private set; }
    public TextView Username { get; private set; }
    public TextView UserAddress { get; private set; }
    public TextView PostTime { get; private set; }
    public TextView PersonThanked { get; private set; }
    public TextView PersonThought { get; private set; }
    public CheckBox LikeUnlikeCheckBox { get; set; }

    public NewsfeedViewHolder(View itemView, Action<int> listener) : base(itemView)
    {
        Image = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView);
        UserDesription = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.DescriptiontextView);
        Username = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.NametextView);
        UserAddress = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.AddresstextView);
        PostTime = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.TimetextView);
        PersonThanked = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.PersonThankedtextView);
        PersonThought = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.PersonThoughtstextView);
        LikeUnlikeCheckBox = itemView.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.likeButton);

        itemView.Click += (sender, e) => listener(LayoutPosition);
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class NewsfeedCardAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    public event EventHandler<int> ItemClick;
    public NewsfeedCardData mNewsfeedCard;

    public NewsfeedCardAdapter(NewsfeedCardData newsfeedCard)
    {
        mNewsfeedCard = newsfeedCard;
    }

    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.NewsfeedCardView, parent, false);

        NewsfeedViewHolder vh = new NewsfeedViewHolder(itemView, OnClick);
        return vh;
    }

    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        NewsfeedViewHolder vh = holder as NewsfeedViewHolder;

        var imageBitmap = GetImageBitmapFromUrl(mNewsfeedCard[position].UserPhoto);

        vh.Image.SetImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        vh.UserDesription.Text = mNewsfeedCard[position].Description;
        vh.Username.Text = mNewsfeedCard[position].UserName;
        vh.UserAddress.Text = mNewsfeedCard[position].Address;
        vh.PostTime.Text = mNewsfeedCard[position].Time;

        if (mNewsfeedCard[position].PersonThanked > 0)
        {
            string personThankedText = "<font color=#36bc9b><b>" + mNewsfeedCard[position].PersonThanked + " Person" + "</b></font> <font color=#333333> thanked</font>";
            vh.PersonThanked.SetText(Html.FromHtml(personThankedText), TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
        }
        else
        {
            vh.PersonThanked.Text = "0 Person thanked";
        }

        if (mNewsfeedCard[position].PersonThought > 0)
        {
            string personThoughtText = "<font color=#36bc9b><b>" + mNewsfeedCard[position].PersonThought + " Person" + "</b></font> <font color=#333333> thought</font>";
            vh.PersonThought.SetText(Html.FromHtml(personThoughtText), TextView.BufferType.Spannable);
        }
        else
        {
            vh.PersonThought.Text = "0 Person thought";
        }

        if (mNewsfeedCard[position].AlreadyLiked)
            vh.LikeUnlikeCheckBox.Checked = true;
        else
            vh.LikeUnlikeCheckBox.Checked = false;

        vh.LikeUnlikeCheckBox.CheckedChange += LikeUnlikeCheckBox_CheckedChange;
    }

    private async void LikeUnlikeCheckBox_CheckedChange(object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsChecked)
        {
            //Need to pass "FeedID" parameter in API below
            var result = await Api.GetLikesUnlikes(FeedID);
            if (result != null)
            {
                if (result.ResponseMessage == "Thanks succeeded")
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public override int ItemCount
    {
        get { return mNewsfeedCard.NumFeeds; }
    }

    void OnClick(int position)
    {
        ItemClick?.Invoke(this, position);
    }
}
```

Any idea how to get the values of model and pass in     LikeUnlikeCheckBox_CheckedChange() mehthod?

Comment: I am not familier with c# code for android but what I can tell you can set the tag for checkable view and when it is checked, from the listener you can get checked view and from there you can get the tag object.

Comment: can you provide me any sample code to set tag?

Comment: In java- android it is simply => `view.setTag(model)` and while getting `Model model = (Model) view.getTag();`